# Pandas: Separating grouping and indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` of financial data:

```
              open    high     low   close     volume
date                                                 
2012-02-13  0.3476  0.3592  0.3449  0.3530  105990679
2012-02-14  0.3470  0.3528  0.3409  0.3429  131799968
2012-02-15  0.3453  0.3513  0.3365  0.3393  119421442
2012-02-16  0.3358  0.3438  0.3271  0.3438  123189697
2012-02-17  0.3488  0.3588  0.3464  0.3546  167932148
2012-02-20  0.3590  0.3682  0.3577  0.3634  127657258
2012-02-21  0.3630  0.3675  0.3524  0.3575  137016196
```

which I am currently grouping as:

```
agg = {'open': lambda s: s[0],
       'high': lambda s: s.max(),
       'low': lambda s: s.min(),
       'close': lambda s: s[-1],
       'volume': lambda s: s.sum()}
```

through

```
df.groupby(lambda d: d.isocalendar()[:2]).agg(agg)
```

This works well except for the fact that my data is now indexed by tuples of `(year, week)`.  I wish for the data to be indexed by the date of the earliest member of the group.  My current hack is along the lines of:

```
agg['date'] = lambda s: s[0]
df2 = df.copy()
df2['date'] = df2.index
df2.groupby(lambda d: d.isocalendar()[:2]).agg(agg).set_index('date')
```

which seems to work however I am wondering if there is a means of separating grouping and indexing so that the group keys do not automatically become the frame index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know the seperation you are looking for does not exist, but ...
assuming the index is sorted (which is also required with your *hack*) a little change to the groupby function gives what you need.

```
In [194]: cache = {}

In [195]: df.groupby(lambda d: cache.setdefault(d.isocalendar()[:2], d)).agg(agg)
Out[195]:
             close    high     low    open     volume
2012-02-13  0.3546  0.3592  0.3271  0.3476  648333934
2012-02-20  0.3575  0.3682  0.3524  0.3590  264673454
```